# how to join a single date column to a time rage table

Tags: sql, join, self-join, presto

table 1 table columns are:

```
cancel_date    product  total_cancels
6/1/2017       a        100
6/1/2017       b        40
6/2/2017       b        10
6/3/2017       b        20
.
.
.
6/1/2018       a        40
6/1/2018       b        10
```

table 2

```
realdate
6/1/2017
6/2/2017
6/3/2017
.
.
.
6/1/2018
```

---

what I want to get

```
product    realdate      total_cancels   cancel_date
a          6/1/2017       100000         6/1/2016-4/30/2017
b          6/1/2017       8000           6/1/2016-4/30/2017
a          6/2/2017       100000         6/2/2016-5/1/2017
b          6/2/2017       8000           6/2/2016-5/1/2017
...
```

so basically sum the total_cancels by realdate, for each realdate, I need to group the canceldate 2-12month.

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- in a tabular format -- would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use aggregate function `sum` .but its strange how you showed output cancels date column that's way . i think that is your typing error

```
    select t1.product, t2.realdate, sum(t1.total_cancels) as total_cancels   
    from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on date(t1.cancel_date)=date(t2.realdate)
    group by t1.product, t2.realdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this out, but might help?

```
select t1.product, t2.realdate, sum(t1.total_cancels) 
from t1 join t2 on t1.cancel_date=t2.realdate
group by t1.product, t2.realdate
```

And I'm not sure I understand what you want in the last column. This is just grouping `total_cancels` by `realdate` per `product`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this question is the same as the one I answered here:
[join start_date and _end_date to another table and sum up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812764/join-start-date-and-end-date-to-another-table-and-sum-up)

What you want to do is join table_2 to the table_1, using the on condition such that table_1. cancel_date is between table_2.cancel_start_date and table_2.cancel_end_date. But first we need to use the DATE_PARSE function to make the dates comparable. Finally just sum up the values.

```
SELECT
  table_1.product,
  table_2.realdate,     
  SUM(total_cancels) AS total_cancels,   
  CONCAT(table_2.cancel_start_date, '-', table_2.cancel_end_date) as start_to_end
FROM table_1 
JOIN table_2
WHERE DATE_PARSE(table_1. cancel_date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
  BETWEEN DATE_PARSE(table_2.cancel_start_date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
   AND DATE_PARSE(table_2.cancel_end_date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
```

Comment: thanks， but if you join table 1 and table 2, do I need to join on a primary key?